# Android How to UPDATE an SQLite table from another table using GROUP BY

Tags: android, database, sqlite, group-by, sql-update

i have an SQLite table with three columns as below

```
Table A
    BOM       Date          Consumption
    salt      Mar 8, 2019    0.7 
    pepper    Mar 8, 2019    0.1
    Rice      Mar 8, 2019    0.8 
    salt      Mar 8, 2019    0.5
    pepper    Mar 8, 2019    0.2
```

I want to group the data in the BOM column such that it sums the values for each group in the consumption table to give me a result as below

```
Table B
    BOM       Date          Consumption
    salt      Mar 8, 2019    (0.7+0.5) 
    pepper    Mar 8, 2019    (0.1+0.2)
    Rice      Mar 8, 2019    0.8
```

my code which is giving me a syntax error for which I am yet to resolve is as below

```
 UPDATE Table_B
    SET
      Table_B_BOM, Table_B_Date, Table_B_Consumption(
      SELECT sum(*)
      FROM Table_A 
    )
```

Comment: Do you want to update table b or insert new rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert rows in `table_b` then:

```
insert into table_b (BOM, Date, Consumption)
select BOM, Date, sum(Consumption)
from table_a
group by BOM, Date
```